# Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery is not get current item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, jquery-ui

I follow this [Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx) 
and this is code

`function uploadFile(){
    $("#statusTxt").text("");
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'Shared Documents';var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var departMent = jQuery('#department option:selected').val();
    var getItemId = null;
    var loader = null;
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
            //console.log(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            //Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {
                getItemId = listItem.d.ID;
                console.log(getItemId);
                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                   $("#statusTxt").text("up load file complete");
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
           });
           getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {
        //console.log(arrayBuffer);
        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
        console.log(fileCollectionEndpoint);
        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
              var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    loader = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        $("progress").val(loader);

                    }
               }, false);

               return xhr;
            },
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
            }
        });
    }
    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {
        console.log(fileListItemUri);
        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileListItemUri.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }
    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {
        //console.log(itemMetadata);
        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        //console.log(department);
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}','Department':'{3}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, departMent+""+getItemId, departMent+""+getItemId, departMent);
        //console.log("body : "+body);
        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: itemMetadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}
// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error.responseText);
    $("#statusTxt").text("can not upload file");
}
}`

When I upload ะwice it's work perfect but when I upload to thrice it show item ID of number 2 I do not know why. anyone can fix this please help thank in advance

this image show result when uploading thrice
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you tried to upload the same document which you uploaded the second time.
Try with a different document or different document name

Comment: Yeah but I changed file name every time that I uploaded

Comment: i copy code from link in my question and I got same result

Comment: It is working for me.Can you check the library if 3 files are uploaded or only 2

Comment: I have checked. it working when I upload a different document but if I want to update my old document so I edit it and upload again but function getListItem return old uri.

Comment: when I delete document in library and upload again console will show the file was deleted by someone

Comment: It upload 3 files but 2 files had name I want and the last was not

Comment: Just try to create 3 new documents with different names and try to upload.It should upload all 3 and then return the 3 new ID's.However if you try to upload a document with the same name it basically overwrites the old one and returns the old ID.

Comment: If you don't want overwrite functionality you can remove overwrite=true from your REST query